# How can I efficiently get a filtered list of svn commits in python?

Tags: python, svn

I'm making an application in python that needs to be able to get information (date, author, files changed) about the latest commits to an svn repository.

I've been trying with the [svn](https://pypi.org/project/svn/) library and my application can get the information it needs by manually filtering through something like this:

```py
import svn.local

repo = svn.local.LocalClient('/my/svn/repo')
for rel_path, entry in repo.list_recursive():
    revision = entry['commit_revision']
    date = entry['date']
```

The problem with this is that it iterates through every file in the repo, getting commit info on the file, and the load time is nearly a minute long on a fairly powerful machine.

If it's possible, I'm looking for some way to iterate through a list of commits starting with the latest revision going back N revisions where N will be provided by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/dsoprea/PySvn#log_defaulttimestamp_from_dtnone-timestamp_to_dtnone-limitnone-rel_filepath-stop_on_copyfalse-revision_fromnone-revision_tonone-changelistfalse) there is a `log_default` method which would allow you to do this easier and even has an option `limit` which could be used to get the `n` items. For example:

```
import svn.local

def print_commits(repo, limit=5):
    client = svn.local.LocalClient(repo)
    for commit in client.log_default(limit=limit):
        revision = commit.revision
        date = commit.date
        print("{}:{}".format(date, revision))

print_commits("repo")
```